# How to create a Table in a OpenDocumentText document using odfpy

Tags: odfpy

I would like to create a table in an `odt` (*OpenDocumentText*) file using [`odfpy`](https://github.com/eea/odfpy)?

The docu of the package is outdated and the project nearly orphaned (but maybe on its way back I think).

Be aware I don't mean Spreadsheet documents but text documents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: The person who raised the question has already solved the problem and also shared a link for reference: [Here](https://mashupguide.net/1.0/html/ch17s04.xhtml)

Following code is the simplest way to create a table and add it to the document. Kindly ask in comments or raise new questions if you want more thing in this regards. (Actually I had to spend a lot of time to understand odfpy and now i want to share the knowledge. :D ):

```
from odf import text, teletype, userfield, table
from odf.table import Table, TableColumn, TableRow, TableCell
from odf.style import Style, TableProperties, TableRowProperties, TableColumnProperties, TableCellProperties
from odf.opendocument import load, OpenDocumentText

dest_file = "test.odt"
doc = OpenDocumentText()

#table styling - Its like CSS in html
table_style = Style(name="table-style", family="table")
table_style.addElement(TableProperties(align="margins"))
doc.automaticstyles.addElement(table_style)

table_cell_style = Style(name="table-cell-style", family="table-cell")
table_cell_style.addElement(TableCellProperties(border="0.05pt solid #000000"))
doc.automaticstyles.addElement(table_cell_style)

table_column_style = Style(name="table-column-style", family="table-column")
table_column_style.addElement(TableColumnProperties(columnwidth="0.2in"))
doc.automaticstyles.addElement(table_column_style)

table_row_style = Style(name="table-row-style", family="table-row")
table_row_style.addElement(TableRowProperties(useoptimalrowheight=False))
doc.automaticstyles.addElement(table_row_style)
#--styling ends here--

# create table 
doc_table = Table(name="xyz-table", stylename="table-style")
# add 11 columns to the table
table_column = TableColumn(numbercolumnsrepeated="11", stylename="table-column-style")
doc_table.addElement(table_column)
"""
#   or you can do the followig for the same as above
for i in range(11):
    table_column = TableColumn(stylename="table-column-style")
    doc_table.addElement(table_column)
"""
# add data of 10 rows in the table
for i in range(10):
    table_row = TableRow()   
    doc_table.addElement(table_row)
    # PUT A TO K IN THE CELLS
    data = ("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K")
    for i in list(data):
        column_data = TableCell(valuetype="string", stylename="table-cell-style")
        table_row.addElement(column_data)
        column_data.addElement(text.P(text=i))
doc.text.addElement(doc_table)
doc.save(dest_file)
#print(dir(doc))
```